# URL Rewriting with a variable before filename

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

Is it possible to implement permalink Structure in a Custom PHP Product? If so could someone guide me how to do so.

I have product with a bunch of PHP Files where head.php is being called in all the pages.

lets say i have index.php, database.php, data.php and foot.php etc

I want the URL to be `http://localhost/********/data.php` in place of `http://localhost/data.php`. Here the admin_name is the custom permalink variable in the custom structure and data.php is any php page in the /var/www/html folder.

Here `********` can be anything which i want to take in take as variable in all the webpages as `$admin_id`.

I have gone through the below URL and am not sure if it will work but could not make it out as i am getting error on `$this->currentURI = parse_url($_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]);` and  `$this->scheme = $this->currentURI["scheme"];`

http://zcourts.com/2011/02/21/creating-a-php-url-mapper-to-parse-fancy-urls-and-query-strings/#sthash.lZnrAo9z.yys9uNUg.dpbs

Comment: That's a really strange requirement. You'd probably have to do this using mod_rewrite or whatever rewrite technology your web server is using prior to PHP receiving the request.

Comment: SO you want to show this URL in browser `http://localhost/foobar/data.php` but want to internally load `http://localhost/data.php` ?

Comment: yes abhinav...more over i want it to be stored in php variable